# NgRx store runtime check NgZone failing on android

Tags: ngrx, ngrx-store

We implemented a network check as a side effect with window event online and offline.

```
online$ = createEffect(() => {
  return fromEvent(window, 'online').pipe(mapTo(NetworkActions.deviceOnline()));
});
```

This works fine in Desktop Chrome and on iOS Safari but somehow results in a `strictActionWithinNgZone` runtime check on Android:

```
    {
      "state": {
        "keyboard": {
          "isKeyboardOpen": false
        },
        "network": {
          "isDeviceOnline": true
        }
      },
      "error": "Error: Action '[Network] Device Online' running outside NgZone. https://ngrx.io/guide/store/configuration/runtime-checks#strictactionwithinngzone"
    },
```

Does anybody have any idea why this only happens in Android and why it even is a problem to begin with?

Edit:
As far as I understand it, fromEvent(window, '...') should always be inside the zone because zone.js does patch all Browser EventTarget.

Also this is on an Ionic + Cordova App but only when built on Android. Only reason I could see for the difference could be in the Webview it is running in but other than that it is just basic RxJS and Angular

Thanks Pascal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this was a super specific problem with an Ionic + Cordova App and the Cordova Network Plugin https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/network

This seems to interfere with the Android Platform. Without the Plugins the Error does not occur but the online and offline window events also never fire on Android. So I guess this has nothing to do with NgRx.